# Cannot view postgres database on one system in another

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin3

I am trying to view a database created on a different system in my current installation of postgres.

I downloaded the same version of postgres (9.6) and replaced the data folder with the data folder from the other system, but when I look at the database in pgadmin, only the default tables are present.

I am also confused by the directory structure.  The directory structure I copied over is /data/base, four number directors and "pgsql_tmp."  What do these numbers mean?

Answer (score 0):

> *I am also confused by the directory structure. The directory structure I copied over is /data/base*

See [Database File Layout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/storage-file-layout.html) in the 9.6 documentation for the explanation of the directory structure.

Your `$PGDATA` seems to be `/data`, thereforce you need to copy all of that.

The reason why you don't see the target databases with the partial copy is probably that `pg_database` is stored in `/data/global`. Note that the fact that the instance starts at all seems lucky. It could refuse to start, or start and become corrupt very quickly. The data files under `$PGDATA/base` are generally not portable across instances, because they contain metadata with transaction IDs.

The `$PGDATA` directory as a whole is portable only if the destination has exactly the same architecture, same operating system and same major version of Postgres.